# Ошибка при добавлении параметра в реестр

Tags: c++builder, реестр

Здравствуйте! Снова пишу на тему реестра, понял как добавлять строковые параметры и шестнадцатеричные, вот вчера писал прогу, 9 параметров успешно получается добавлять, стал 10 добавлять, отключать DWatson(стандартный отладчик) через реестр, написал код, всё перепроверил, правильно, компилируется, при добавлении параметра нажатием button вылезает ошибка добавления параметра с исключением. Вот ошибка:

> > Project Project1.exe raised exception class ERegistry with message 'Failed to set for 'Auto '. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue

Подскажите что это может быть, может нужно како-й то доступ прописывать на C++ , к этому разделу?

Вот исходник:

```
TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry;
reg->RootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
reg->OpenKey("\SOFTWERE\\Microsoft\\WindowsNT\\CurrentVersion\\AeDebug",true);  
reg->WriteString("Auto", 0);  // Watson disable 
reg->CloseKey();

Application->MessageBox("Параметр добавлен, значение 0 ", "Registry", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
delete reg;

exit;
```

Comment: а если запустить программу с правами администратора?

Comment: Попобую, ну я и так админ оута сам собрал его ....

Comment: не так делаете. нужно правой кликнуть по exe файлу правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать "запустить от имени администратора"

Comment: Блин так и делал, я свой проект сохраняю на внешнем диске и прекрасно знаю что там компилируется exe . Подскажите лучьше как добавить параметр если прога запущена не от администратора?

Comment: По правильному - нужно получить права администратора, можно и программно. А можно в [манифесте прописать](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/cb8af5c1-8b06-4d14-a1f3-ed0203354e0c).

По неправильному - искать уязвимости в винде. Но это тема другого форума.

Comment: Права админа сделал всё равно ошибка Failed to set data for 'Auto'

Comment: Похоже ещё здесь

    "\SOFTWERE

лишний слеш. либо нужно два. Да и  наверное `SOFTWARE`

Comment: Такае-же ошибка Failed to set data for 'Auto' там главное чтоб слеш был двойной в последующих папках реестра иначе будет длинная строковая папка ..... я поставил <code>\\SOFTWERE также-ошибка</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, надо убрать слэш, который у Вас в начале строки. Путь указывается без начального слэша. Во вторых, Вы ошиблись немного в самом пути. Нужно писать "SOFTWARE", а не "SOFTWERE".

```
TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry;
reg->RootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
reg->OpenKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\WindowsNT\\CurrentVersion\\AeDebug",true);
reg->WriteString("Auto", 0);  // Watson disable
reg->CloseKey();

Application->MessageBox(L"Параметр добавлен, значение 0 ", L"Registry", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
delete reg;
```

Проверил на билдере XE3 - все работает.

Comment: Работает ! Правдо не сразу  получилось , параметр писался не в то место, косяк с моей стороны. Спасибо! Да благословит тебя господь !

Comment: Почитайте про блок try catch. Оберните весь блок работы с реестром в try. Когда вы запустите свою программу не из под компилятора, то она уже не будет выдавать никаких ошибок. Можете посмотреть тут: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/Try-Catch-Throw.php

Comment: А мой ответ в комментарии к вопросу, где собственно говорилось о том же ответе, что и у @Dobby007, автор вопроса не осилил...

Comment: @Dobby007 А что это за чувак?  988 уважений начиная с мая 2011 года оХрИнЕтЬ!!! Это надо-же от интернета не отрываться (ну это я так отступился к вашему комментарию).(((автор вопроса не осилил... Значит этот чувак С++ боиться

Comment: @Programmist Syvorov, Вам тоже удачи и да поможет Вам Бог. Да я не так уж и много знаю то)))